# Handling a WebRTC byte[] stream?

Tags: node.js, audio, socket.io, webrtc

I'm basically trying to record audio chunks from a webrtc stream, I've been able to send the binary data with help of this resource [HTML Audio Capture streaming to Node.js](https://subvisual.co/blog/posts/39-tutorial-html-audio-capture-streaming-to-node-js-no-browser-extensions).

Im using [netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio), as this library plays well with socket-io on the client side.
Here are my server endpoints:

```
server.addEventListener("audio-blob", byte[].class, (socketIOClient, bytes, ackRequest) -> {
    byteArrayList.add(bytes);
});

server.addEventListener("audio-blob-end", Object.class, (socket, string, ackRequest) -> {
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayList.getArray());
    AudioInputStream audiIn = new AudioInputStream(in, getAudioFormat(), 48000l);
    AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;
    File wavFile = new File("RecordAudio.wav");
    AudioSystem.write(audiIn,fileType,wavFile);
});
```

The format settings:

```
public static AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
    float sampleRate = 48000;
    int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
    int channels = 2;
    boolean signed = true;
    boolean bigEndian = true;
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits,
            channels, signed, bigEndian);
    return format;
}
```

Im using this class to collect the byte arrays (and yes I know the risk with this solution)

```
class ByteArrayList {
   private List<Byte> bytesList;

   public ByteArrayList() {
       bytesList = new ArrayList<Byte>();
   }

   public void add(byte[] bytes) {
       add(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
   }

   public void add(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length) {
       for (int i = offset; i < (offset + length); i++) {
           bytesList.add(bytes[i]);
       }
   }

   public int size(){
       return bytesList.size();
   }

   public byte[] getArray() {
       byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesList.size()];
       for (int i = 0; i < bytesList.size(); i++) {
           bytes[i] = bytesList.get(i);
       }
       return bytes;
   }
}
```

The generated wav file only plays noise though, no recording is present. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey man not sure if you're set on this solution, but I would strongly suggest using a WebRTC Media Server like Kurento to handle recording WebRTC streams. They have a node bindings lib. You can then use Twilio for STUN/TURN to make sure the connection between your client/server is always routable regardless of the network.

Comment: I looked att Kurento before starting this project, seems like a nice framework for Websocket/webRTC project. The reson I'm not using Kurento is that this proof of concept help me the understand Websocket and webrtc communication.

Comment: I see! Well good luck man. In order to understand the low-level WRTC communication, I believe you will need to understand how to get at the underlying stream via DTLS-SRTP. DTLS is the management protocol of the keys that encrypt the underlying SRTP stream. I don't know much about that low down in the stack, but Janus may be a good place to see how it's written in C: https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway

Answer (score 0):

When Google:ing around for answers I stumbled upon this resource [how to save a wav file](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/4339/how-to-save-a-wav-file-using-audiosystem-and-audioinputstream-of-javasound)

What I was doing wrong is that I had a fixed size on the AudioInputstream constructor parameter:

```
new AudioInputStream(in, getAudioFormat(), 48000l)
```

changed it to the:

```
new AudioInputStream(in, getAudioFormat(),byteArrayList.getArray().length);
```